# Error Type: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc lstsq_n

Tags: python, numpy, loops, types, signature

I read some questions of other users with similair problems but none of them could help me with my problem. Maybe I did not understand them or got the gist of the problem or solution.
So I making a post with my Error Type.

The Error is :
No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc lstsq_n

above was also this information:

```
 x, resids, rank, s = gufunc(a, b, rcond, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
```

I think this line of code is my problem but i do not really understand how to fix it.

```
'''V_RAP,resid,rank,s = np.linalg.lstsq(np.transpose(B_matrix_lenk),D)'''
```

The output of D is = `[ 0.          0.         -0.01397506  0.          0.          0.        ]`

and for B_matrix_lenk =

```
[[-0.17260388555249162 -0.11428353476468595 -0.13975062454742207
  -0.7052915177679927 matrix([[0.06097224]])]
 [-0.9817859286926897 -0.030101581594337838 -0.988058752355563
  -0.705340427032332 matrix([[0.23104628]])]
```

.

> Maybe the problem is that the elements are incorrect and mixed together.

I thank you in advance for your ideas and solutions :)

Comment: why does `B` contain the `matrix` objects?  It's dtype must be `object`.  The ufunc must be expecting numeric dtype arrays,

Comment: @hpaulj thanks for your comment and hints. After some tryouts I figured it out with your hints and it worked.